# How do I make wine bottle reflections blue?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass

In my photographic work I've often desaturated the blue tint that appears in the highlights on red wine bottles but now creating them in Blender I'm finding the subtle tint adds a great level of realism. If you image search on the net for red wine bottles you'll see all the slicks/highlights on the glass have a tiny tint of blue to them.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this in Cycles? I can do it in LuxCore (reflection colour is part of the glass material) but I'd like to stick to Cycles if it's possible!

Secondly, does anyone have any idea why this actually happens? Green glass, white light, blue tint!

Answer (score 0):

If you want tinted reflections without tinted transmission, you can put your glass together manually-- it's relatively simple.  It's just a refraction BSDF mixed with a glossy BSDF on the basis of Fresnel:

[image]

Shown here with a red reflection, but of course, you can use anything you'd like.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, that looks like the way to go. I was trying to do the bottle with volume absorption but you really can't see any of that once you have the red wine combined with the green bottle so this method will be much simpler too!